# Are there any scriptural justifications in Islam that justify the extermination of the Jews?

Tags: jews, jizya

I'm not trolling and I sincerely apologise if this question offends anyone. I also want to get it out of the way that I don't believe that all Muslims are violent and genocidal. I also don't believe that Islam is inherently violent and genocidal, and that is exactly why I'm asking this question, because I'm a bit confused about the situation between Islam and Israel and the Jews.

There are certain groups of Muslims that seem to support total annihilation of Jews world-wide. (Eg. Hamas) It also seems to be a stock, politically incorrect joke in popular culture (eg. in the Sacha Baron Cohen movie "The Dictator" the main character is a parody of a middle-eastern dictator, and one part of his policies and agenda is to exterminate Jews).

I understand that there is significant tension in the Holy Land between Jews and Muslims today and that blame can't be put all on one side. So I can kinda understand why certain groups would want to destroy Israel (not that I agree). What I don't understand is this push for global genocide. Doesn't the Qur'an promote peace and tolerance of "People of the Book"? I thought that a religious tax towards Jews was as bad as it is supposed to get? And I've heard that historically, Jews and Muslims have got on pretty well (Jews are even permitted to pray in Mosques!)

My actual question: Is there a theological/religious justification for this recent push to exterminate Jews worldwide? (ie, is there some verse in the Quran which can be (mis)/interpreted to support this?) Or are these groups motivated purely by tribal vengeance and bloodlust?

Comment: There is no verse in the Qur'an or hadith about extermination of Jews or any other group of people. So it will be difficult to answer your question as it stands. There are hadith about prophecies at the end of times, analogous to Armageddon and the rapture, where specific groups of people are saved, and others that die, but there is no direct order to go exterminate any specific group. Is it possible to edit your question with specific points that you want addressed (and to make it less inclined towards politics and more on Islam)?

Comment: I'm new to this so I really dont know what it's true and what it isnt. But I've read this in Wikipedia: "Following the emigration, the people of Mecca seized property of Muslim emigrants to Medina.[118] War would later break out between the people of Mecca and the Muslims. Muhammad delivered Quranic verses permitting Muslims to fight the Meccans" . "Muhammad expelled from Medina the Banu Qaynuqa, one of three main Jewish tribes,[14] but some historians contend that the expulsion happened after Muhammad's death." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad

Comment: More on the same, "After signing the truce, Muhammad assembled an expedition against the Jewish oasis of Khaybar, known as the Battle of Khaybar. This was possibly due to housing the Banu Nadir who were inciting hostilities against Muhammad, or to regain prestige from what appeared as the inconclusive result of the truce of Hudaybiyya.[137][167] According to Muslim tradition, Muhammad also sent letters to many rulers, asking them to convert to Islam (the exact date is given variously in the sources)"

Comment: More on the same "Shortly thereafter he expelled the Banu Qaynuqa, one of the Jewish tribes at Medina that had been threatening his political position, and who had assaulted a Muslim woman which led to their expulsion for breaking the peace treaty." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Badr

Comment: @Pablo Muslims have lived peacefully in muslim lands for centuries, but their relationship has turned sour because of the situation in Palestine. It is not through religion but rather because of politics.

Answer (score 2):

Your question may be split into sub questions, and sounds that there is a misunderstanding that has to be clarified.

1 - There is no single place in Islamic teachings/rules that requests killing of innocent souls, regardless of its faith, except in very clear cases.(mostly transgression that results in killing of innocents)

2 - Taxes are taken from both Muslims and non-muslims in the Islamic states.

3- People of the book, christians and Jews who are living amongest Muslims are to be protected, and granted full freedom to practise their belief system.

4 - There is a problem with the word jews in context I think you should differentiate between Judaism and zionism, killing, terror and the mess we are seeing is politically ideological, and has nothing to do with valid Islamic resources.

One last note: There are many extremist Muslims who would consider non-muslims as enemies, remember you can see the same in christians, jews, and even other religions.. so the thing is, lack of knowledge and understanding is what makes people generalize it, and point at the faith system.

Comment: Can you provide a Hadith that says that People of Book are to be protected those who live among Muslims and to have full freedom to practice their belief system? And provide also other Hadiths of what you claim in your answer please.

Answer (score 1):

[**In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Just.**][1]

**Answer:**

Look, in Quran does not say anything like that, maybe you have misunderstood it. If we were for example to start WW3 with intention to exterminate Jews we would be like Adolf Hitler, right? He is the one who wished to exterminate Jews and that is not correct at all. Islam is a religion of peace and it is against violent. God Almighty Says:

> ”Fight in the way of God those who fight you but do not transgress. Indeed. God does not like transgressors.” [**(Q2:190) **][2]

In here it means that God orders us only to fight in self defense only.

God Says:

> ”Kill the idolaters wherever you find them, and capture them, and blockade them, and watch for them at every lookout...” **(Quran 9:5).**

The “idolaters” (Arabic: mushrikeen) were those Meccan “pagans” who had declared war against Muhammad and his community. The Meccan oligarchs fought against the Prophet’s message from the very beginning. When they realized that the flow of converts to Islam was increasing, they resorted to violent oppression and torture of the Prophet and his followers. The Prophet himself survived several assassination attempts, and it became so dangerous for the Muslims in Mecca that Muhammad sent some of his companions who lacked tribal protection to take asylum in the Christian kingdom of Abyssinia. After 13 years of violence, he himself was compelled to take refuge in the city of Medina, and even then the Meccans did not relent in their hostilities. Eventually, various hostile Arab tribes joined in the fight against the Muslims, culminating in the Battle of the Trench, when 10,000 soldiers from many Arab tribes gathered to wipe out the Muslim community once and for all. As we know, the Muslims survived these challenges and eventually went on to establish a vast civilization.

If the enemy inclines toward peace, however, Muslims must follow suit: “But if they stop, God is most forgiving, most merciful” (2:192). Also read: “Now if they incline toward peace, then incline to it, and place your trust in God, for God is the all-hearing, the all-knowing” **(8:61).**

There’s a verse of a Hadith that says that prophet Muhammad of God ordered us to protect People of Book(Jews and Christians).

prophet Muhammad (pbuh) said:

> “Whoever kills a mu‘ahid (non-Muslim living under Muslim rule) will not smell the fragrance of Paradise, even though its fragrance may be detected from a distance of forty years.” **Narrated by al-Bukhari**

So in here it is about a Muslim who kills a non Muslim unjust.

God Says:

> ”And if anyone of the Mushrikoon (polytheists, idolaters, pagans, disbelievers in the Oneness of God) seeks your protection then grant him protection so that he may hear the Word of God (the Qur’aan) and then escort him to where he can be secure”. **[al-Tawbah 9:6]**

In 628 AD, a delegation from St. Catherine’s Monastery came to Prophet Muhammed and requested his protection. He responded by granting them a charter of rights, which I reproduce below in its entirety. St. Catherine’s Monastery is located at the foot of Mt. Sinai and is the world’s oldest monastery. It possess a huge collection of Christian manuscripts, second only to the Vatican, and is a world heritage site. It also boasts the oldest collection of Christian icons. It is a treasure house of Christian history that has remained safe for 1,400 years under Muslim protection.

The promise to St. Catherine:

> ”This is a message from Muhammad ibn Abdullah, as a covenant to those who adopt Christianity, near and far, we are with them.
>   Verily I, the servants, the helpers, and my followers defend them, because Christians are my citizens; and by GodI hold out against anything that displeases them.
>   No compulsion is to be on them. Neither are their judges to be removed from their jobs nor their monks from their monasteries. No one is to destroy a house of their religion, to damage it, or to carry anything from it to the Muslims’ houses.
>   Should anyone take any of these, he would spoil God’s covenant and disobey His Prophet. Verily, they are my allies and have my secure charter against all that they hate.
>   No one is to force them to travel or to oblige them to fight. The Muslims are to fight for them. If a female Christian is married to a Muslim, it is not to take place without her approval. She is not to be prevented from visiting her church to pray. Their churches are to be respected. They are neither to be prevented from repairing them nor the sacredness of their covenants.
>   No one of the nation (Muslims) is to disobey the covenant till the Last Day (end of the world).”

This means that it is not permitted at all for Muslims to fight against Jews and Christians, this is only after Sun Rise from West.

Prophet Muhammad said:

> ”Beware!  Whoever is cruel and hard on a non-Muslim minority, curtails their rights, burdens them with more than they can bear, or takes anything from them against their free will; I (Prophet Muhammad) will complain against the person on the Day of Judgment." **(Abu Dawud)**

This is just an idea so that you can have a better understanding

I hope it is a good answer.

Comment: You maybe should comment on the question title at least a bit:* "What is the motivation behind the “Destroy all Jews” attitude that some Muslim groups/communities have adopted?"*

Comment: Definitely. As Kilise said, consider rephrasing your question. Honestly, this question does not contribute to the educational goals of this site. It is really a statement disguised as a question. If it we’re sincerely intended for learning, it could have asked if the Quran tells us to dislike Jews or something along those lines. Can we vote to close it?